# How can I move smooth the scene view camera according to the checked true/false door position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script is attached to each door and change the door color red or green depending on the state in the editor. If in the editor I'm unchecking/checking a checkbox of the door it will change it's color and the lock state :

The script have the [ExecuteAlways] attribute so I can change the lock state and color of the door/s in editor mode too.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class HoriDoorManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<DoorHori> doors = new List<DoorHori>();
    public bool doorLockState;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (transform.parent != null)
        {
            Transform parent = transform.parent;
            var children = parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

            if (children != null)
            {
                foreach (Transform door in children)
                {
                    if (door.name == "Door_Left" || door.name == "Door_Right")
                        doors.Add(door.GetComponent<DoorHori>());
                }
            }
            ColorDoors(Color.red, Color.green, doorLockState);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        if (doorLockState == false)
        {
            if (doors != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < doors.Count; i++)
                {
                    doors[i].OpenDoor();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        ColorDoors(Color.red, Color.green, doorLockState);
    }

    private void ColorDoors(Color red, Color green, bool state)
    {
        List<Transform> children = new List<Transform>();

        for (int i = 0; i < doors.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (Transform child in doors[i].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
            {
                if (child == doors[i].transform)
                    continue;

                var renderer = child.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                renderer.material.shader = Shader.Find("Unlit/ShieldFX");

                if (state == true)
                {
                    renderer.material.SetColor("_MainColor", red);
                    LockState(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    renderer.material.SetColor("_MainColor", green);
                    LockState(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public bool GetLockState
    {
        get { return doorLockState; }
        set { doorLockState = value; }
    }

    private void LockState(bool state)
    {
        var collider = gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();

        if (state == false)
        {
            collider.size = new Vector3(2.3f, 2.736307f, 2.5f);
            collider.center = new Vector3(0, 1.378154f, 0);
            collider.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-1.57f, 0, -2.98f);
            collider.isTrigger = true;
        }
        else
        {
            collider.size = new Vector3(2.3f, 2.736307f, 3);
            collider.center = new Vector3(0, 1.378154f, 0);
            collider.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-1.57f, 0, -2.98f);
            collider.isTrigger = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Second script is the manager :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorsLockManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public List<HoriDoorManager> Doors = new List<HoriDoorManager>();

    // The global state
    [SerializeField] private bool _globalLockState;

    // During runtime use a property instead
    public bool GlobalLockState
    {
        get { return _globalLockState; }
        set
        {
            _globalLockState = value;

            // apply it to all doors
            foreach (var door in Doors)
            {
                // now you would need it public again
                // or use the public property you had there
                door.doorLockState = _globalLockState;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        var doors = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door");
        Doors = new HoriDoorManager[doors.Length].ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < doors.Length; i++)
        {
            Doors[i] = doors[i].GetComponent<HoriDoorManager>();
        }
    }
}
```

The third script is the editor :

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(DoorsLockManager))]
public class DoorsLockManagerEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _doors;
    private SerializedProperty _globalLockState;

    private bool shouldOverwrite;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _doors = serializedObject.FindProperty("Doors");
        _globalLockState = serializedObject.FindProperty("_globalLockState");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        serializedObject.Update();

        shouldOverwrite = false;

        // Begin a change check here
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_globalLockState);
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            // overwrite only once if changed
            shouldOverwrite = true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < _doors.arraySize; i++)
        {
            var door = _doors.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);

            // if door == null the script itself has an error since it can't even find the SerializedProperty
            if (door == null)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("There was an error in the editor script!\nPlease check the log", MessageType.Error);
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't get door property", target);
                return;
            }

            if (door.objectReferenceValue == null) continue;

            var serializedDoor = new SerializedObject(door.objectReferenceValue);

            var lockState = serializedDoor.FindProperty("doorLockState");

            serializedDoor.Update();

            if (lockState == null)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("There was an error in the editor script!\nPlease check the log", MessageType.Error);
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't get lockState property", target);
                return;
            }

            // HERE OVERWRITE
            if (shouldOverwrite)
            {
                lockState.boolValue = _globalLockState.boolValue;
            }
            else
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(lockState, new GUIContent("Door " + i + " Lockstate"));
            }

            serializedDoor.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Last script is where I'm moving the scene camera :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class SceneViewCameraMove : ScriptableObject
{
    [MenuItem("Test/Move Scene View Camera")]
    static public void MoveSceneViewCamera()
    {
        Vector3 position = SceneView.lastActiveSceneView.pivot;
        position.z -= 10.0f;
        SceneView.lastActiveSceneView.pivot = position;
        SceneView.lastActiveSceneView.Repaint();
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of the editor of the doors states :

[image: Doors states]

Now what I want to do is that each time I'm changing one of the doors lock state in the editor move the scene view camera and position it in front the changed door state in some distance so I can see the door location area.

I wanted to make a map of my all scene view or space ship and then to indicate some how all the doors but colors maybe.

But the idea here is to quick move the scene view camera to the changed lock state door position instead moving with the mouse each time.
That way I can see each door location area and to decide how to use it in the game later.

Example of the camera standing in front of a door. But now I need each time to move with the mouse and find the door I changed it's lock state. I want to make the camera move automatic to the door.

[image: Door]

Or maybe there is a nice way to draw/create a map not mini map but a map that will work in the editor mode so I can see the doors locations and colors something maybe in 2d ?

Comment: One way that comes to my mind is make a script that can be attached to the door(s) which finds the camera of interest, records its current position/rotation, locks the character so it doesn't move, then interpolates the camera to some offset of the door's position to display the door state change, and finally interpolates back to the camera's initial position.